# Quelle préposition utiliser avec le verbe « affecter » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, droit-et-justice

Dans l'extrait suivant :

> Le bien immeuble par destination doit être **affecté à** l'exploitation 
>   ou être définitivement attaché à l'immeuble par nature.

pourquoi utiliser *affecter à* et pas *affecter* (sans préposition) ou *affecter par* ? Ni [le Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/affecter) ni le Larousse ne parlent d'une telle distinction.

Comment: [Définition 1 du Larousse en ligne](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/affecter/1414?q=affecter#1411) : Destiner quelque chose à un usage particulier.

Comment: @Kareen: Merci. Pourriez-vous signaler où Larousse traite-t-elle ce contraste ?

Comment: Quel contraste? *affecté à* fait clairement référence à la définition indiquée par @Kareen, et à cette définition seulement. En revanche, *affecté par* n'aurait aucun sens dans la phrase donnée en exemple, à moins de dire *affecté **par** le propriétaire **à** l'exploitation*.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de constraste entre « affecter à » et « affecter par ». « Affecté par » n'est pas un idiome, c'est un passif parfaitement ordinaire.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le *Littré* cité en dernière ligne :

> Terme de finance : 
>    **Affecter** une somme **à** un payement, **à** un service, la destiner à
>   ce payement, à ce service.

Le petit Robert

> AFFECTER : Du latin médiéval 1551 *affectatus*  qui a donné
>   *[affaitement](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/affaitement)*.
>
> - Destiner, réserver à un usage ou à un usager déterminé (synonyme *imputer*)
>    *Les crédits que le budget a  **affecté à** l’Éducation nationale*.
> - de *affectation* 1899  : Procéder à l'affectation de quelqu'un : 
>    *Il s'est fait **affecter à** la météo*.

---

**Correction**

Il existe deux autres origines latines pour affecter: *affectare* et *affectus*, ce qui donne en tout trois définitions différentes qui occupent un petit quart de page dudit dictionnaire.

Aucun des exemples cités dans ces entrées n'utilise *par*.

Or il semble que l'*[usage actuel](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/affecter+par.html)* lui attribue une forme intransitive, ce qui n'est pas dans *[le Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/affecter)* ni d'ailleurs dans l'Académie française qui présente aussi trois formes transitives.

La tournure des phrases avec la forme transitive n'est plus dans l'air du temps et l'évolution de l'usage transitif n'est pas encore accepté.

Answer (score 1):

**Il y a 2 tournures, et plusieurs sens**

**tournure *affecter* + COD + *à*:**

*Affecter quelqu'un / quelque chose à une destination/un lieu/un emploi*: destiner, muter, la personne/la chose à/vers cette destination.

[voir ici le CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affecter/2)

**Forme transitive: *affecter* + COD:**

*Affecter quelqu'un / quelque chose*: le toucher émotionnellement (la personne), modifier son état / son fonctionnement pour une chose (souvent de manière négative: perturber, mais pas nécessairement ):

> affecter son travail, le cours des choses ...
>
> Une personne très affectée.

La forme *affecté par* est la seconde forme utilisée à la voix passive:

> Une personne très affectée par cette nouvelle.

On peut aussi avoir *affecté par ... à* :

> Il est affecté par sa hiérarchie à cette nouvelle mission.

[Voir ici le CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affecter/1)

**Et encore l'autre sens de la forme +COD**: adopter une attitude, afficher, faire semblant:

> Il affecte l'indifférence.

[Voir ici le CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affecter/0)